# Is it possible to query uniswap for new tokens?

Tags: graphql, web3js, uniswap

Is it a possibility to run a query against the Uniswap API that gives back all new tokens created on that date?

Or would it have to be built some other way?

Comment: The day the token was created or the day it was listed on uniswap.  You can query the event logs in the RPC to see the contract creation and obtain the block time stamp.

Comment: For now i would like to see both.  But keep in mind i dont know the contract as a priori.

Comment: You can pull the json list, but I don't think its a versioned package so you won't be able to see the listing date.  Then you can just query the event logs to the creation, so atleast you have when to token was created

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Can you show how to pull the list?

Comment: I think it's this https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipns/tokens.uniswap.org I just googled it but I would confirm to make sure